# no option to add affinity group to virtual network azure

Tags: azure, azure-affinity-group

The option to specify an affinity group when creating a virtual network in azure seems to have disappeared from the form. I can still attach to a location though. How do I get this option back.

Comment: screenshot would make this question clearer.

Answer (score 3):

Hello Dear,

This option have intentionnaly been replaced by the Region/Location as you said.
Regional Virtual Networks are supposed to be more appropriate than affinity groups.
For more information, you can go here : http://azure.microsoft.com/blog/2014/05/14/regional-virtual-networks/

Obviously, if you still want to bring back the Affinity group, then try this:

Create a Virtual Network from the Management Portal
Download the Virtual Network Configuration File

Edit the appropriate file section to get

`<VirtualNetworkSitename="VNetDemo" AffinityGroup="VNetDemoAG">`

instead of

`<VirtualNetworkSitename="VNetUSWest" Location="West US">`

Then, delete the previously created virtual network and import your file in the management portal to recreate the network with your defined settings.

Answer (score 2):

Microsoft released Regional VNETs at Tech ED 2014. A Regional VNET is created on a region rather than an affinity group. Eventually, all existing Affinity Group VNETs will be migrated to be Regional VNETs. Since Regional VNETs provide significantly enhanced capabilities all new VNETs should be Regional VNETs and there is no reason whatsoever to create an Affinity Group VNET. That is presumably why you can no longer create Affinity Group VNETs in the Azure Portal.

New [features](http://convective.wordpress.com/2014/06/01/network-connectivity-in-azure/) include: Internal Load Balancer, Public Instance-Level Public IP Addresses, VNET-VNET connections, etc.

Comment: According to the following document, you may still want to use affinity groups if you want the lowest latency between VMs possible.  So there's definitely a reason to still use them, no?

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-networks-migrate-to-regional-vnet/